# How to get the number of pages of a .PDF uploaded by user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jquery-plugins, adobe

I have a file input, and before "uploading" i need to calculate the number of pages of that .pdf in JAVASCRIPT (eg. JQuery...)

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: Also, you can limit the size of the file that can be uploaded to your site, if you're worried about excessive page counts.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In case you use pdf.js you may reference an [example on github](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js) ('.../examples/node/getinfo.js') with following code that prints number of pages in a pdf file.

```
const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist');
...
pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath).then(function (doc) {
    var numPages = doc.numPages;
    console.log('# Document Loaded');
    console.log('Number of Pages: ' + numPages);
})
```

Comment: One closing `)` is missing as the last character.

Answer (score 14):

and a pure javascript solution:

```
var input = document.getElementById("files");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
reader.onloadend = function(){
    var count = reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
    console.log('Number of Pages:',count );
}
```

Comment: That regular expression works for documents fulfilling a number of assumptions and in particular is likely to fail for documents with multiple revisions or intense object stream use.

Comment: i tested it on many pdf docs and it works. do you have any sample?

Comment: I could create any number of samples: As you surely are aware, the PDF format at byte level allows to add comments; thus, I could simply add any number of comments containing a "/Type /Page" to an existing document and so make the regular expression return a too high result. But you probably don't mean constructed examples but real-world ones. For that you might want to look at questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30236358/1729265) etc.

Comment: I am getting this message - Property 'match' does not exist on type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.
  Property 'match' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `pdf-lib`.

You will need to read the file from the input field and then make use of `pdf-lib` to get the number of pages. The code would be like this:

```
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib';

...

const readFile = (file) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
}

const getPageCount = async (file) => {

  const arrayBuffer = await readFile(file);

  const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(arrayBuffer);

  return pdf.getPageCount();
}
```

And then just get the number of pages of the attached file with:

```
const numPages = await getPageCount(input.files[0]);
```

being `input` the variable which stores the reference to the DOM element of the file input.

Comment: I think the correct function to only get the page count is `getPageCount`. `getPages` will return an array of `PDFPage` objects: https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfdocument#getpagecount

Comment: thx @danbtl, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated in the other answers, something like pdf.js is be what you are looking for. I've taken a look at the API and it does include a numPages() function to return the total number of pages. It also seems to count pages for me when viewing the [demo page from Mozilla.](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

It depends if you are able to use modern browsers and experimental technology for your solution. pdf.js is very impressive, but it is still experimental according to the [github page](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) .

If you are able to count the pages on the server after uploading, then you should look at [pdftools](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/pdftools.1.html) or similar.

Something like `pdftools --countpages` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

In typescript class using Pdf-lib I use the following.

```html
// getPAGE COUNT:
  async getPageCount(formUrl: any): Promise<number>{
    const LogPdfFields = [] as any[];
    const formPdfBytes = await fetch(formUrl).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes);
    const pageCount = pdfDoc.getPageCount();
    return pageCount;
  }
```

Call as a promise

Answer (score 0):

I think the API has changed a little since Tracker1 posted an answer.  I tried Tracker1's code and saw this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: pdfjsLib.getDocument(...).then is not a function
```

A small change fixes it:

```
const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist');
...
pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath).promise.then(function (doc) {
    var numPages = doc.numPages;
    console.log('# Document Loaded');
    console.log('Number of Pages: ' + numPages);
}
```