# pdf.js : How can we get the current pdf page number using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf.js

I want to get the current **page number** from **pdf.js** when user

Click's some Button.I'm not opening pdf file in **iframe** like that

Below link

[using iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873181/how-can-i-get-the-current-pdf-page-number-from-pdf-js-iframe)

I'm using the pdf.js Directly From the [GitHub Project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

My Question is how can I get the Current page Number from

**pdf.js**

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35887722
..........................
..........................

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber` is a [getter and setter](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/d08895d6591b8b3233676a2ffa6a2c294cb70df7/web/pdf_viewer.js#L127-L158). Examples:

```
// Go to page 5
PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = 5;

// Move two pages forward
PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber += 2;
```

Comment: In my case am using PDFJS.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber . But its undefined.

Comment: PDFJS.pdfViewer._currentPageNumber worked for me. This is late but somebody looking for this can find it useful