# PDF page count using regex

Tags: regex, pdf

I used regex to calculate page count for pdf. Below is the code that i used.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());
return matches.Count;
```

It works fine with the version below 1.6 but not working with pdf files with version 1.6 . It returns 0 page if pdf version is 1.6 .

Comment: *It works fine with the version below 1.6* - there are many pre-1.4 documents you will get the wrong result for, and many 1.6+ documents you will get non-0 results for.

Comment: Never do this - using Regex with PDF to count anything is stupidly dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you most likely have to do with 1.6 documents which make use of the then introduced feature of compressed object streams. As in such documents the information you search for is compressed, your regular expression does not find it.

There are tools which allow you to decompress such streams in a file before searching it. Before you look for them, though, be aware that the result of your code cannot be trusted anyway as

- there can be more matches than pages because there may be old, unused page objects or even other wrong positives in the file,
- there can be less matches than pages because PDF allows alternative ways to write those type entries.

Comment: Thanks for the info . Ya i will change the method of page count . It is not reliable if that is the situation with pdf.

Comment: PDF is a complex format one should not try to use without a tool or library specially designed for PDF support.

Comment: Is iTextSharp is the only Dll that can be used for PDF ? Or is there any other Dll available ?

Comment: There are others, too, with different strengths and weaknesses, usable under different licenses. As my main environment is java, though, I don't know in detail which there are.