# Is there a way to count doc, docx, pdf pages with only js (without Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, pdf, docx, doc

I need to count number of pages in doc, docx and pdf files.
I know that it is possible to do with PHP, NodeJS

But is it possible to do it with only javascript if file is on server?

Comment: It isn't possible for code on one computer to process data on another computer without first copying that data into local memory… but that shouldn't be a hardship in the context of the WWW.

Comment: http://www.electronmedia.in/wp/pdf-page-count-javascript/...for  pdf only

Comment: @soni8010 yes, thx for it.
Also I hope to find solution for doc, and docx but internet is full of php and nodejs results

Comment: @WinK- I did it for pdf only.I am posting my answer could you please up it?

Comment: a pure javascript solution for pdf files: [How to get the number of pages of a .PDF uploaded by user?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39222676/2179157)

Answer (score 3):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-pdf-pagecount can be used to get docx and pdf page count.

```
const getPageCount = require('docx-pdf-pagecount');

getPageCount('E:/sample/document/aa/test.docx')
  .then(pages => {
    console.log(pages);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });


getPageCount('E:/sample/document/vb.pdf')
  .then(pages => {
    console.log(pages);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Hi Baum description added

Comment: Looks better now, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this.)

Comment: is this pure js as requested ? or does this involve Node.js ?

Comment: it uses nodejs concepts

Answer (score -2):

```
**To find out page number of PDF files**

<script src="js/pdf.js?1444224269"></script>
PDFJS.workerSrc    =   "js/pdf.worker.js";
var fileLocation   =   'test.pdf';
var numPages    =   0;
PDFJS.getDocument(fileLocation).then(function(pdf) {
numPages   =   pdf.numPages;
});
```

Answer (score -3):

First you need to download zip file from [here](http://www.electronmedia.in/wp/images/pdf_pagecount/EM_PDFPageCount_JSlib.zip)

after that

- Include the PDFPageCount.js library into your target page
- Call the function in the format

**PDFPageCount.getPageCount(target PDF file,callback function);**

***EXAMPLE***

**PDFPageCount.getPageCount("HTML5_draft.pdf", callbackFunc);
**

Once the page count is detected the callback function will get the page count as a return parameter