# php/javascript - count total number pages pdf

Tags: javascript, php

Is there any way to count the pages of a pdf that is not `ImageMagick`?

Many regex scripts do not always work.

`ImageMagick` works but is very slow. Having a shared hosting I do not have the possibility to use Pdfinfo. In case I can also use javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the number of pages of a .PDF uploaded by user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253669/how-to-get-the-number-of-pages-of-a-pdf-uploaded-by-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Comment: What is the function called? Ty

Comment: I've never used it before, but as I know it has a property called numPages which is what you want.