# Javascript - total pages number pdf with PDF.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

How do I get the total page count with pdf.js?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var pdf = pdfjs.getDocument('test.pdf');
  alert(pdf.numPages);
});
</script>
```

Comment: is that not what `numPages` returns?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23960868/4464204

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about pdfjs but you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    pdfjs.getDocument('test.pdf').then(function(pdf){
        alert(pdf.numPages);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I solved with "pdfjsLib.getDocument('test.pdf').then(function(pdf)". Ty!